# Symfony 5 - how to add field to form from One To One relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have got two entities with One to One relation - User and UserExperience. How can I add UserExperience fields to User form? Which field type should i use? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I know now. I used collection type and that was fine. You have to use prototype in view like:
`{{ form_row(form.emails.vars.prototype) }}`